# Problem with pipes. Pipe terminates when reader done

Tags: pipe, fifo

I am on OSX, using bash, trying to make sense of pipes. I wish to let a program communicate in two directions with a bash shell. I want to set this up in such a way that this is always the same shell, so that I can cd to some directory and bash will remember (rather than using a new bash shell all the time).

What I have tried so far is this. From a new terminal (A), do

```
mkdir /tmp/IOdir
cd /tmp/IOdir
mkfifo pToB
mkfifo bToP
tail -f -1 pToB | bash >> bToP
```

Then, to test this connection, I can do, from a new terminal (B)

```
cd /tmp/IOdir
echo echo hello > pToB
```

and from a third terminal (C)

```
cd /tmp/IOdir
(read myline &&  echo $myline) < bToP
```

This behaves how I want. The same bash shell stays active, and the output comes through on the other side. Call this state of affairs X, so that I can refer later to it.

**Onward from state X**

However, now, from this state X, we cannot do the same thing again. That is, if we do from terminal (B)

```
echo echo hello > pToB
```

and then from terminal C

```
(read myline &&  echo $myline) < bToP
```

Then nothing comes through in terminal C. Moreover, if we again do, from terminal B

```
echo echo hello > pToB
```

The bash shell closes.

What I could have done in state X was first do, from terminal C

```
(read myline &&  echo $myline) < bToP
```

and then from terminal B

```
echo echo hello > pToB
```

In this case hello comes through at terminal C, and it seems like we are in state X again. So we can basically repeat this forever. Now this might seem sufficient for two way communication, but my program is such that if it requests a new line like this

```
(read myline &&  echo $myline)
```

and there is no new line, it will "hang" (just like bash, in fact I mean to use a call to bash in the program). It is therefore not able to send input to pToB after that and there is nothing I can do.

**Questions**

Is there a way to set this up without doing too much programming in C? Is there a way to do this more elegantly without using two named pipes? What is causing the pipe to close in one scenario, and not in the other?

**Edits**

From [this page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe), we have

> Full-duplex (two-way) communication normally requires two anonymous pipes.

On one hand, it seems at least I have the right number of pipes. On the other, I am using named pipes, not anonymous ones. So maybe this will be hard/impossible.

Furthermore mkfifo [gnu/linux source](http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/0_9_14/libc/sysdeps/linux/common/mkfifo.c) is likely defined in terms of mknod [gnu/linux source](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/sbin/mknod/mknod.c.html), which is also a unix command. But I'm not sure if much can be learned from that.

[Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html) is an introduction to pipes in C, including the linux source of pipe. Maybe that can tell us why a pipe gets closed, if that is indeed what happens.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5957386/2550739) is a related question about preventing that fifos get closed. I tried tying the pipes to background sleeping processes as was done in an answer tere but that didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange.com! Thank you for including lots of details in your question. Make sure to stop by the [help page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @EvanTeitelman thanks for the warm welcome. I looked at the help page. I also edited my question a bit. Do you know if it is possible to add invisible/comment text to a question? For example, I was not allowed to put more links in here. I figured maybe somebody could edit and put them in for me. Anyway it does not matter in this case, I don't think people care about the source of mknod :P.

Comment: You can use HTML-style comments: `<!-- comment text -->`. If you add the links as comments, I'll make them real links for you.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman thank you. I have edited the question, but maybe the other brackets ( () and [] ) we interfering. It would be nice if it looked like (gnu/linux source), with the brackets.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman this is fine too, thanks again :).

Comment: Can bash hang off / on to a domain socket?

Comment: @MelBoyce I do not know, I would think so. But a domain socket is not exactly the same as I fifo it seems, though it seems very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the cause, use `strace`.

```
tail -f | strace bash >> foo
```

The second `echo echo hello > pToB` gives me then this:

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "e", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "c", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "h", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "o", 1)                         = 1
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "h", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "e", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "l", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "l", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "o", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "\n", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "hello\n", 6)                  = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3299, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

So, the second time it tries to write hello\n, it gets a broken pipe error; that's why you can't read hello (it was never written), and bash quits so that's the end of it.

You'd have to use something that keeps the pipe open, I guess.

How about this?

```
(while read myline; do echo $myline; done) < pToP
```

For more background information, `man 7 pipe` may be relevant, it describes the various error cases around pipes.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to frostschutz answer, consider the following table

[image]

The first time we try to send hello into the bToP, it gets blocked until there is also a reader for the fifo. The second time we, the reader sends back a SIGPIPE signal, which terminates bash. Even if we could ignore that, we would probably run into the EPIPE error after that.

I think what I am trying to do is impossible. My application cannot "read and write at the same time". I think I will have to make an intermediate program capable of keeping both sides of the pipe open.